# Auto delete Wordpress users according to time since registering?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, cron

On a basic Wordpress 3.1 setup with User Access Manager, is it possible to automatically delete users that are x days old?

I have found no plugins for this feature. How would one go about implementing this? Would I be able to set up a cron job with an sql or php query whereby users that are for example 3 days old are automatically deleted from the database once every day? If so, could someone please explain how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance.

Comment: Want to point out that this seems to be the only available resource online for this question - immensely helpful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to have a look at the `user_registered` column in the `wp_users` table. Since you're using WordPress, I'll assume that you're also using MySQL — in which case you can use the `DATEDIFF()` function in your SQL to work out how many days ago they registered.

The SQL to delete everyone who is 30 days old (or older) is:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_users` 
WHERE datediff(now(), `user_registered`) >= 30
```

You can replace the `DELETE FROM` with `SELECT * FROM` in that query to see which users the delete would affect, if you want to preview who will be deleted by the query.

You could set this up as a cronjob using the language of your choice, which might be a PHP script that just runs the SQL above. You could then run that at midnight every day by putting the following into your crontab:

```
0 0 * * * php ~/delete_expired_users.php
```

If you're new to cronjobs, then that will simply run the command `php ~/delete_expired_users.php` every day (that's that the `*` denotes) at hour `0`, minute `0` (ie. midnight). Let me know if you need any more detailed instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this sounds exactly what I'm looking for. If it's not too much trouble could you give some more detailed instructions? I'm not really familiar with sql/php, I'm a frontend developer and a client is pretty set on having this. Many thanks once again, really appreciated

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this tutorial](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/02/19/php_foundations.html) which will take you through simply connecting to a database and performing a query. Make sure you take backups!

Comment: And don't forget, if someone gives an answer that you feel answers your question, it's a good idea to mark it as accepted - just hit the big green tick next to that answer.

Comment: Thanks - it's working, however it is selecting the admin account for deletion too. Is there a way to prevent, say, the first 2 accounts with ID 1 & 2 from being deleted with this query? Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: You just need to add WHERE id > 2 at the end of that SQL query.

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID &gt; 1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3` when adding `WHERE id > 2` at the end of the query? My MySQL version is 5.0.92

Comment: Swap the second WHERE for an AND. You can only have one WHERE in a statement. Learn some SQL - great thing to know!

Comment: Thanks again, looks like I'll have to purchase a book and educate myself. If there is any way to give additional rep let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would recommend using a couple of in-house features of Wordpress that will do a neater job of this for you.

The first is to use [wp_delete_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_user) - this will not only remove the user record, but also wipe any associated user_meta and posts, thus keeping your database nice and clean.

The second recommendation is to use [wp_schedule_event()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) - part of the `wp-cron` set of functions. This might be preferable if you don't have the flexibility or access to set up a crontab on your current host (note about using this below).

```
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_dailyClearOut');

function my_clearOldUsers() {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE datediff(now(), user_registered) > 30");

    if ($oldUsers = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_N)) {
        foreach ($oldUsers as $user_id) {
            wp_delete_user($user_id[0]);
        }
    }
}

add_action('my_dailyClearOut', 'my_clearOldUsers');
```

This should do the trick for you (this is exactly what I'm using at the moment).

It's worth noting that 'wp-cron' functions are *not* the same as a standard crontab - they are only fired when a user accesses the site, and thus are nowhere near as precise as a standard cron. However, for this particular functionality, you may find this is fine.

Hat-tip to @Sam for the `datediff()` function - that's neat!

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that wp_schedule_event() will be fired at every page load, which might compromise your site. Better to check if we already have a scheduled event and only than add it.

```
if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_dailyClearOut' ) ) {  
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'my_dailyClearOut' );  
}
```