# Delete all the authors and their post automatically after x days in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, author

I wanted to ask if there is the possibility of eliminating, for example, all users authors and their post automatically after x days from the date of registration. 
For example, if an author after its registration, write the post, after x days, both the author and the post will be permanently deleted, automatically.

Comment: How about a cron job? Perhaps there are more elegant options.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response, and I’m sorry if I expressed myself badly.
The WP-Cron executes functions perfectly, but what I want is to eliminate “every author after 365 days from the date of its registration.”
Example:

A author enrolls the 2014/01/01;
The author is automatically deleted 2015/01/01.

A author enrolls the 01/06/2014;
The author is automatically deleted 01/06/2015.

A author enrolls the 03/01/2014;
The author is automatically deleted 03/01/2015.

etc. etc.

Is it possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Research [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp-cron) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=delete+user+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. As explained in this post [Auto delete Wordpress users according to time since registering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304229/auto-delete-wordpress-users-according-to-time-since-registering) ,
by inserting the following code, you delete the registered users from more than 30 days.

```
if(!wp_next_scheduled('my_dailyClearOut')){

        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_dailyClearOut');  }

        function my_clearOldUsers() {
        global $wpdb;
        $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE datediff(now(),               user_registered) > 30");
        if ($oldUsers = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_N)) {
        foreach ($oldUsers as $user_id) {
            wp_delete_user($user_id[0]);
        }
     }
  }
        add_action('my_dailyClearOut', 'my_clearOldUsers');
```

Unfortunately did not work with "SELECT ID FROM" but works with "DELETE FROM"

Working:

```
if(!wp_next_scheduled('my_dailyClearOut')) {

        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_dailyClearOut');  }

        function my_clearOldUsers() {
        global $wpdb;
        $query = $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $wpdb->users WHERE datediff(now(), user_registered) > 30");
        if ($oldUsers = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_N)) {
        foreach ($oldUsers as $user_id) {
            wp_delete_user($user_id[0]);
        }
     }
  }
        add_action('my_dailyClearOut', 'my_clearOldUsers');
```

Now the problem is that it also eliminates the administrator.

Is there a way as to eliminate only registered users from more than 30 days with a particular role (eg. Authors)?

Or delete all users except the Administrator and the Editor?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, I noticed that removes only the user, but does not remove the post and the associated user metà.
Any idea?